# React: How to handle the click event on a shared Header component?

Tags: css, reactjs

So I have a shared Header component between different components, where I handle the routing and manage the clicked/active index. In this instance I created a clickable component that checks if the element has an isActive prop and handles the styling accordingly (color change). My solution only works if I click twice on the header element: the redirection works on the first click, but the styling will only work if I click it twice.

Here's my header code:

```
export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: null
    };

    this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleItemClick(index) {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: index });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="header">
          <nav className="header__navbar">
            <NavLink to="/" className="link">
              <MyClickable
                name="Cars"
                className="header__item"
                index={0}
                isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 0}
                onClick={this.handleItemClick}
              />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/Players" className="link">
              <MyClickable
                name="Players"
                className="header__item"
                index={1}
                isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 1}
                onClick={this.handleItemClick}
              />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/Calendar" className="link">
              <MyClickable
                name="Calendar"
                className="header__item"
                index={2}
                isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 2}
                onClick={this.handleItemClick}
              />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/Reddit" className="link">
              <MyClickable
                name="Reddit"
                className="header__item"
                index={3}
                isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 3}
                onClick={this.handleItemClick}
              />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/Livestreams" className="link">
              <MyClickable
                name="Livestreams"
                className="header__item"
                index={4}
                isActive={this.state.activeIndex === 4}
                onClick={this.handleItemClick}
              />
            </NavLink>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I realize the handleItemClick only triggers during the second mouse click, since the component has to render, but I'm missing the logic on how to make it work on first click.

I also tried to directly change the links css with link:active/focus but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st click cannot update the styling, because the activeIndex will be reset to null.

The child component's constructor will be called when the parent re-rendered. Let's say you are on page A and want to go to page B:

1) first click on B, activeIndex A -> B

2) react router make page B rendered, header will be rendered as part of page B, activeIndex: B -> null

3) second click on B: activeIndex null -> B, style got updated

There are 2 solutions for this:

1) move the header out of the page and shared in higher level (e.g. out of the react router)

2) use the Redux store to keep the index state.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I went with your first solution and moved up the header, and now conditionally render every component (without using any routing). Now my question is: is there any way to change the url every time I render a component?

Comment: happy to help, and for the url question, you could use BrowserRouter in React Router. check this example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter